# error:a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

Tags: c++, static, enums

I don't understand why view gives me the error of a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object.

`CDrawView::Shape` is an enum that i have declared on my `CDrawView`

```
enum shape{line, rect, elli};
shape current_shape;
```

This is my other class

```
class Shapemaker
{
public:

    CDrawView view;
    static void Create(CDrawView::shape )
    {
        if(view.current_shape == view.line)
        {
            view.m_shape.reset(new Line());
        }
        else if(view.current_shape == view.rect)
        {
            view.m_shape.reset(new Rect());
        }
    }
}
```

What's the best practice to avoid this error

Comment: You need to understand the difference between static and non-static members.  The basic solutions are (a) make you member function non-static, or (b) make your member variable static.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, since the function is `static`, it doesn't have access to `view`. That's because `view` is a non-static member of `Shapemaker`, so is only associated with specific instances o `Shapemaker`. Either `view` needs to be `static` or the `Create` function shouldn't be. The other alternative is that `view` shouldn't be a member and should be created inside the `Create` function.

Also, the enum constants' names are within the scope of the `CDrawView` class and are accessed through the class name like so:

```
if(view.current_shape == CDrawView::line)
```

The `.` operator is for accessing a non-static member of an object. `view` does not have a non-static member called `line` or `rect`.

Answer (score 1):

`view` is a non-static object of class CDrawView,  `Create` is  static function of `ShapeMaker` class, there will be no instance of `view` if you do not construct an object of `ShapeMaker` while `Create` is not associated with any objects of ShapeMaker. You cannot use nons-tatic members inside a static member function.